# How to avoid the malicious image URL in the forums

Tags: javascript, html, cookies, frontend

In my forums i allow the user to enter the image URL in the message body but user can enter any random URL(instead of image URL), which can ask user the credentials like in this SO post [Prevent HTTP Basic Authentication from displaying prompt for images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33586139/prevent-http-basic-authentication-from-displaying-prompt-for-images) .

Solution given in above post is not useful for me as i am tracking the user cookie and adding `crossorigin="anonymous"` will not allow browser to send the cookie and without my website wont function.

Is there is any easy to implement solution available , also it would be possible if anybody let me know how Stackoverflow does it.

Comment: when you are giving a user to enter something uncontrollable there are so many hacks you can't prevent. Image urls can look like images, behave like those, but underneath exploit so many flaws. That's why you see a lot of websites that only allow to upload an image.

Comment: Uhm, perhaps you're misunderstanding… `crossorigin="anonymous"` means that no cookie will be sent *to the server hosting the image*. Cookies will still be sent to *your* server.

Comment: @deceze , could you provide the links also explains this in detail.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/CORS_settings_attributes - Even purely logically speaking… the browser will send a request, including cookies, to your server; it receives HTML as response, and the HTML response contains an `<img crossorigin="anonymous">`… there's no way this image can prevent the browser from sending cookies *to you first*.

Comment: @deceze , how i should add this in my code ? and is there is any easy way to test this on local system i mean i have a code and on click of which it opens a basic auth popup in browser , i added `crossorigin="anonymous"` in the img tag but still on click on url it opens a popup.